# How to call "cart_payment.method" API of magento using XMLRPC in Android

Tags: java, android, magento, xml-rpc

I have tried many different ways to call "`cart_paymant.method`" `API` of `Magento` using `XMLRPC` but always failed.

Below is the code that I used to call it.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("method","checkmo");
//map.put("po_number",null);
//map.put("cc_cid", null);
//map.put("cc_owner",null);
//map.put("cc_number",null);
//map.put("cc_type",null);
//map.put("cc_exp_year",null);
//map.put("cc_exp_month",null);


Object[] paymentMethod=new Object [] {map};
Object param1[]=new Object[]{shoppingCartId,paymentMethod};
Object param2[]=new Object[]{Utils.sessionId,"cart_payment.method",param1};   

try 
{
  Boolean ans=(Boolean)client.callEx("call", param2);
  Log.i("Payment Method Setting : ", ""+ans);
}  
catch (XMLRPCException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return 0;
}
```

***Exception that I get:***

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize null
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:99)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:89)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:72)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:72)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCCommon.serializeParams(XMLRPCCommon.java:36)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCClient.methodCall(XMLRPCClient.java:253)
at org.cws.magentoAnd.xmlrpc.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:174)
```

***FYI, I am also posting the php code provided on Web which calls that API.***

```
$paymentMethod = array(
    “method” => “checkmo”
);

$resultPaymentMethod = $proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    “cart_payment.method”,
    array(
        $shoppingCartId,
        $paymentMethod
    )
);
```

Comment: Is shoppingCartId initialized?

Comment: @BryanGlazer : Yes,Actually It's a global variable..and I have checked well in advance that none of the variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

I've got `sessionId` from login, but when I call a method (example: `catalog_category.info`) it throws exception:

> XMLRPC Fault: Calling parameters do not match signature.

Here is my code:

```java
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      uri = URI.create("http://gameshay.net/magento/index.php/api/xmlrpc/");
      client = new XMLRPCClient(uri);
      String sessionId = "";
      try {
         sessionId = (String)client.call("login", "mdev", "socbay123");
         Log.d("MY_XMLRPC_SUCCESS_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         final Map<String, Object> category = (Map<String, Object>) client.call("call" Object[]{sessionId, "catalog_category.info","5"});
      }
      catch (XMLRPCException e) {
         Log.d("MY_XMLRPCException_MSG", e.getMessage());
      }
      return null;
   }
}.execute();
```

Comment: The error means that you are not passing the arguments in the correct way or may be in correct order.